# New Button style Image not showing

Tags: wpf, binding, styles, styling

I am making a style for button to appear in a custom way [image]

The Idea is to write the Image source in the Tag property and the Text in the Content property

So the style goes like this

```
<Style x:Key="NormalButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,4,12,4"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Source="{TemplateBinding Tag}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{TemplateBinding Height}"/>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" Grid.Column="1" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">

                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>

                    </Trigger>

                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Image does not display and only the Text apears

I call the button like this in the MainWindow

```
<Button Style="{DynamicResource NormalButtonStyle}" Tag="/iPARK;component/Resources/Sign%20out_icon.png" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="20" Click="Signout_Click"/>
```

If I set the image in the style file directly like this then it shows but then it cannot be reused for other images

```
<Image Source="/iPARK;component/Resources/Sign%20out_icon.png" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{TemplateBinding Height}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put an image URI into the `Tag` property it will not automatically be converted into an `ImageSource` (as it is done for the `Image.Source` property). You need to do that explicitly:

```
<Button ...>
    <Button.Tag>
        <BitmapImage UriSource="/iPARK;component/Resources/Sign%20out_icon.png"/>
    </Button.Tag>
</Button>
```

Comment: I had The Tag changed to the format you said and changed the <image/> in the style to <ContentPresentor/> and that did the trick, Thank you